# How to make a 4D numpy array from 2 2D numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, reshape, numpy-ndarray

I have 2 2D numpy arrays with shape `(160000,91)`.

`160000` means all pixels of an image `(200x800)`, `91` means # of images.

`U(160000,91)` and `V(160000,91).`

How to create a numpy array `X` with shape `(91,200,800,2)` with `X(:,:,:,0)` = `U(91,200,800)` and `X(:,:,:,1) = V(91,200,800)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transpose to move the batch dimension to axis 0. Then reshape the two arrays and stack them along a new axis 3:

```py
import numpy as np

U = np.random.random((160000, 91))
V = np.random.random((160000, 91))
X = np.stack((np.reshape(U.T, (-1, 200, 800)),
              np.reshape(V.T, (-1, 200, 800))),
             axis=3)
print(X.shape)  # (91, 200, 800, 2)
```

Comment: What is -1 mean? I got this output shape (1, 200, 800, 2), not (91,200,800,2).

Comment: One axis may be `-1` meaning its shape will be calculated automatically by numpy. Here it'll be replaced by `91`. This might be handy if the number of images changes (i.e. you don't have to hard-code `91`).

Comment: Thank you! It works like a charm. The key work "stack" is exactly function I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
U = np.reshape(U, (91,200,800))
V = np.reshape(V, (91,200,800))

X = np.stack((U, V), axis=3)
```

Comment: This will not work since it mixes the batch dimension with image data